# Create a file server side via a simple PHP/HTML page

Tags: php, file, text, submit, field

I am trying to create a HTML/PHP file in which a user inputs a file name to  a text box, clicks submit, then that file is created in the same file folder in the directory

Here is what I have so far, Unfortunatley this my 3rd of fourth attempt, deleting and restarting. I cannot promise it is the best version

```
<?php 

function addExtension($fileName) {
    return ($file) + ".txt";
}

if (isset($_POST['prefix'])) {
    $result = ($file), (intval($_POST['prefix']));
}

$ourFileName = addExtension;
$ourFileHandle = fopen($fileName, 'w') or die("can't open file");
fclose($ourFileHandle);
?>
<html>
<body>

    <?php if (isset($result)) { ?>
        <h1> Result: <?php echo $result ?></h1>
    <?php } ?>
    <form action="" method="post">
    <p>File name of file to be created <input type="text" name="prefix" /></p>
    <p><input type="submit"/></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Im not even sure If I'm on the track any more, any help would be great,

Thanks

---

UPDATE!!!
With the help of the answers below and a few hours I believe I am getting somewhere, But still not 100% there.

Here is what I have.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>File Creation</title>
<?PHP

$prefix = $_POST['prefix'] ;
$extension = ".css" ;

$ourFileHandle = fopen($prefix, 'w') or die("can't open file");
fclose($ourFileHandle);
?>
</head>
<body>
<FORM NAME ="form1" METHOD ="POST" ACTION = "basicForm.php">
  <INPUT TYPE = "TEXT" VALUE ="username" NAME="prefix">
  <INPUT TYPE = "Submit" Name = "Submit1" VALUE = "Login">
</FORM>
</body>
</html>
```

It works as I expect and desire. the issue I'm having is creating the function to combine "$prefix and $extension". I know its something simple, and I have been over it in tutorials previously but which ones I cannot seem to find for the life of me. any more help would be much appreciated!

Just if anyone is curious my intention eventually is to have the script create a file within a folder of the same name, inside a specified folder. The file will be a css file and the contents dynamically changed through the same form.

Thanks Again!

---

Solved it

Below is the final code/

```
<html>
<head>
<title>File Creation</title>
<?PHP
if ( isset( $_POST['Submit1'] ) ) { 
$prefix = $_POST    ['prefix'] ;
$extension = ".css" ;
print "File " .$prefix . $extension . " Created";
$ourFileHandle = fopen($prefix . $extension, 'w') or die("can't open file");
fclose($ourFileHandle);
}
?>
</head>
<body>
<FORM NAME ="form1" METHOD ="POST" ACTION = "fileCreationFormV2.php">
<INPUT TYPE = "TEXT" VALUE ="File Name" NAME="prefix">
<INPUT TYPE = "Submit" Name = "Submit1" VALUE = "Create">
</FORM>
</body>
</html>
```

I was looking over an old contact form id created and it hit me " . ".

Thanks to everyone for their help!

Comment: What do you mean by "in the same file folder"? You mean you want to enable to user to create files _inside_ the folder where your php files are stored? Don't! That is a _huge_ security gap!

Comment: Eventually I wish to progress so that it creates a folder of the same name within a specified folder (which I'm assuming solves mentioned security gap). But as I am relatively new PHP I thought it best to attack the most basic function first and build up. Thanks for looking out for a fellow user though (Y)

Comment: Sure, experimenting is always a good thing. Keep up the work, but also keep in mind potential issues you raise. But most important is: always keep in mind that you might raise issue you do not know about. That is the tricky bit ;-9

Answer (score 1):

In your function,

```
function addExtension($fileName) {
return ($file) + ".txt"; // here you cannot call $file, you can call $fileName 
}
```

I didn't understand your this line

```
$result = ($file), (intval($_POST['prefix']));
```

In this line

```
$ourFileName = addExtension; // you have to call like addExtension('your file name goes here')
```

Then,

```
$ourFileHandle = fopen($fileName, 'w') or die("can't open file");
```

It should be

```
$ourFileHandle = fopen($ourFileName, 'w') or die("can't open file");
```

Comment: Thanks for your Help, This along with a few hours of fiddling has put me in a better position, but I am still not 100% There, I am about to add to my post with my progress.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['prefix'])) {
$prefix=$_POST['prefix'];
$filename=$prefix . '.txt';
$ourFileHandle=fopen($fileName, 'w') or die("can't open file");
echo 'done!';
fclose($ourFileHandle);
}
else
{
echo '<html>
<body>
    <form action="" method="post">
    <p>File name of file to be created <input type="text" name="prefix" /></p>
    <p><input type="submit"/></p>

</body>
</html>';
}
?>
```